# Opening python file with an input

Tags: python, file

Here is the code I have so far:

[image]

How can I make this program open another python file, using this method or similar (you have to open it from a variable)?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here.  Do you want to run the code from the other file or manipulate it as text?

Comment: Code for first part: file = ("test.py")
import file

Comment: second part is just print ("File Opened")

Comment: and I'm trying to run the code from the other file

Comment: I have inlined your image and reworded your question, but it still needs work. Please don't paste code as screenshots. Images can't be searched or copied, and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function, for to execute an external script,

```
file = "test.py"
exec(open(file).read())
```

you get,

```
File Opened!
```

Comment: I'm going to try and explain the problem best I can:

Comment: I have a code that looks for a line in a text file. The line I'm looking for ends in .py e.g. One of the lines in the text file is: iPhone5C16GB.py, and that it also the name of the python file I want to open. That line is then saved into a variable. When I try and open the text file with the variable name I get this error message:                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TEST\Task 3\Final code task 3.py", line 28, in <module>
    exec(open(file).read()) #opens it
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'iPhone5S16.py\n'

Comment: any help or do i need to redesign?

Comment: @googlecoolcat you must use `strip` function, before, this remove `\n` character [string doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)